# Invalid object name in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have created as stored procedure, but when I try to get the data in `ptask` I get the following error

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure mySproc, Line 72 [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid object name 'ptask'.
```

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE procedure PSBASPLG.ipMirrorFromOffer
    @usr    nvarchar(255),
    @age    int,
    @id     int
as
set nocount on
declare @now datetime = getdate()
exec ipLgAppend @usr, 'PSBASPLG.ipMirrorFromOffer', @pint0 = @id

;with stask (tsID, tsTag, tsNode, tsTxt, cuID, pjRef, pjRsp)
as (select top 1
        ts.tsID, ts.tsTag, ts.tsNode, ts.tsTxt,
        pj.pjCust, pj.pjRef, pj.pjRsp
    from tbTasks as ts
        inner join tbProjs as pj
        on  (pj.pjID = ts.tsProj)
    where
        (ts.tsID = @id)
)
, sleaf (lfTag, lfTxt)
as (select  distinct 
        lf.lfTag, lf.lfTxt
    from tbLeafs as lf
        inner join stask as ts
        on  (ts.tsNode = lf.lfNode)
)
, sline (paTxt, paCnt, paSta, tyID, rsID, itID, acTyp, grID)
as (select  distinct 
        pa.paTxt, pa.paCnt, pa.paSta, pa.paTyp, pa.paRes,
        it.itID, ac.acTyp, pa.paGrp
    from tbParts as pa
        inner join tbActs as ac
        on  (pa.paAct = ac.acID)
        inner join stask as ts
        on  (ts.tsID = ac.acTask)
        inner join tbItems as it
        on  (it.itID = pa.paItem)
    where
        (pa.paStk >= 0) and
        (pa.paSta > -1) 
)
, ptask (tsID, tsProj, tsNode)
as (select  distinct
        ts.tsID, ts.tsProj, ts.tsNode
    from tbTasks as ts
        inner join tbLeafs as lf
        on  (lf.lfNode = ts.tsNode) and
            (lf.lfTag = PSBASPLG.fnConf('Leaf_offertag'))
        inner join stask as sl
        on  (sl.tsTag = lf.lfTag)
    where
        (ts.tsSta > -1)
)
, pline (paID, itID, acID)
as (select  distinct
        pa.paID, pa.paItem, ac.acID
    from tbParts as pa
        inner join tbActs as ac
        on  (pa.paAct = ac.acID)
        inner join ptask as ts
        on  (ts.tsID = ac.acTask)
    where
        (pa.paStk >= 0) and
        (pa.paSta > -1) 
)

select * from ptask -- Error happens here
```

Why is `ptask` an invalid object?

Comment: Can you post the whole query? It's hard to discern without it.

Comment: @robopim: Ofcourse. I've added the missing parts now

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh great point, it's 4am for me and I completely assumed SQL Server

Comment: @jarlh: I've tried running it in both SSMS and EMS. The error output is from SSMS

Comment: In looking at this again, I see another sproc being executed. Have you verified the code in that sproc is valid?

Comment: @robopim: You're right. The problem is not in that sproc, but in the inner join beneath, that join makes the ptask selection empty, which gives the error. If you could create an answer for this I would gladly mark is as solved